# Connection impossible when using "usage-stats-url: jdbc:postgresql://localhost/postgres"

Tags: r, docker, shinyproxy

I'm trying to store the shinyproxy stats in a PostgreSQL database, to do this, I created a database and the event table like indicated on the documentation.

This problem is similar to the one occurred with influxdb ...
I also tried with the monetdb, same result.

[image]

My shiny app work well without the `usage-stats-url: jdbc:postgresql://localhost/postgres` line in the `application.yml` file

[image]

But when I add the following line, I can no more connect to my apps.

```
#usage-stats-url: jdbc:postgresql://localhost/postgres
#usage-stats-username: postgres 
#usage-stats-password: postgres
```

The shinyproxy is launched with docker-compose, thanks for any help.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It cause error because you can not access the postgresql db inside your host machine using localhost. Because your container refering localhost to itself.Therefore when you add `usage-stats-url : jdbc:postgresql://localhost/postgres` to `application.yml` file it try to find a db inside your container instead of the host machine.